# SQLCommand SqlParameter Default Column Value in UPDATE C#

Tags: c#, sql

How to set Default Value as Value of SqlCommand SqlParameter?

SqlCommand is the class contained in System.Data.SqlClient

My Schema does not accept DBNull.Value as value

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("column_1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1) { Value = DBNull.Value });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As lboshuizen points out, if your "schema" isn't taking null, or the parameter of the stored procedure or query cannot be null, trying to give it a null value will likely fail. In this case, you need to see why you are trying to set it to null if you know it doesn't accept it. I would surmise an empty string as opposed to null would work, or something else that is sensible.

The `SqlParameterCollection` property `Parameters` has an `AddWithValue` method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

You can simply insert `null` and that will be handled for you:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter", null);
```

If you cannot provide a null, you can provide something like an empty string:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@parameter", "");
```

You also very rarely need to specify the data type using this mechanism.

Comment: @lboshuizen In that case he cannot pass null or `DBNull.Value` and one wonders why he is trying.

Comment: He wants to provide a default to avoid the dbnull

Comment: Ok using your second option works, but' there is nothing like DBnull.Value for Default? Something like DBdefault.Value ? I'm dreaming?

Comment: @andrea If the column doesn't take nulls then that won't work.

Comment: command.Parameters.AddWithvalue("@parameter", ""); this has worked

Answer (score 1):

If the schema doesn't accept null it indicates that the column is mandatory and requires a sensible value.

Using a default value for a column is a property of the schema.

1. So either alter the schema to provide a default.

   `ALTER TABLE {TABLENAME} 
   ADD {COLUMNNAME} {TYPE} {NULL|NOT NULL} 
   CONSTRAINT {CONSTRAINT_NAME} DEFAULT {DEFAULT_VALUE}`
2. Choose a valid (not null) default value in your application code and use it as a value in the parameter.

   `const string default = "unknown";
   ...
   SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
   command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("column_1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 1)
   { Value = default });`

*Note: Changing the schema to accept NULL is considered cheating :-)*